# mysql binary log only log deletes

Tags: mysql, binary, logging

Is there any way in MySQL to only log deletes?  I tried using the mysql binary log option but unfortunately, there are too many inserts to my database and the file swells instantly.  If I let it grow for more than a day or so it will take up all the room on the server. I just want to log deletes for disaster recovery purposes. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A log file contains all changes to a database.  It can be used to [roll a backup forward](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html):

> After a backup file has been restored,
>   the events in the binary log that were
>   recorded after the backup was made are
>   re-executed. These events bring
>   databases up to date from the point of
>   the backup

But in order to roll a database forward, the log has to contain all updates, not just deletes.  So I don't think you can change it to just log deletes.

Is it an option to make full backups more often?  After a [full backup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-policy.html), you delete the old log files.  That's a good way to keep the size of the binary log under control.

> The MySQL binary logs take up disk
>   space. To free up space, purge them
>   from time to time. One way to do this
>   is by deleting the binary logs that
>   are no longer needed, such as when we
>   make a full backup:
>
> ```
> shell> mysqldump --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data=2 \
>      --all-databases --delete-master-logs > backup_sunday_1_PM.sql
> ```